# Show loading progress bar untill ReactJS web app is fully downloaded?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm using ReactJS and since SPA applications serve the initial index.html then download the rest of the html/javascript/css using AJAX calls, could you create an accurate loading bar using the progress events on those AJAX calls?

Does anybody know how you could accomplish this in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I've accomplished this in the past is a little hard coded, but works. Essentially, I have two variable in the state. One is for `loadingProgress` representing overall loading progress. This is the value the user sees. The other is `numOfAjaxCalls`. This represents the total amount of ajax calls that need to be made. I use this internally to calculate `loadingProgress`.

Basically, I use ajax's **request progress** to determine the status of any individual ajax call. In my `xhr.onprogress` function I update the state with this calculation:

```
const loadingProgress = event.loaded / (event.total * (100 * this.state.numOfAjaxCalls));
this.setState({
    loadingProgress: loadingProgress
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do you get a handle on the React's ajax calls and how many there are? The index.html is generated by React isn't it?

Comment: It's generated by your bundler. Everything else is on the same server as the index file (unless you're including scripts from CDNs). I actually misread your initial question. My method's loading starts when the app has loaded and I start doing calls for data. I'm not aware of any way to access React's internal requests to resolve your included files. However, I do know that this takes place before components are mounted, so unless your app is resolving an abnormal amount of scripts, or you're requesting from an abnormally slow server, I don't think the user would notice.

Comment: It's also worth noting that React doesn't load html, it uses Javascript to build the DOM. To my knowledge, external JS and CSS are the only things that React needs to fetch. Everything else is included in your bundle and loaded as a single .js/.css file, which is loaded by your browser, not React itself.

Comment: I'm using webpack to bundle my ReactJS project. It injects the script tags that download the rest of the bundle in the index.html using the HtmlWebpackPlugin. I wonder if there's some way to customize it so that I can progress on the bundle downloads.